# Intellij IDEA crashes with "@NotNull parameter 'modalComponent'"

Tags: intellij-idea

I have OS- Linux, IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1  Build #IC-223.8214.52, JDK: 19.0.2 and sometimes it crashes on opening new Maven projects with empty main window and following exception in the log:

`2023-02-03 07:55:04,046 [  33818] SEVERE - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - Argument for @NotNull parameter 'modalComponent' of com/intellij/ide/IdeEventQueue.consumeUnrelatedEvent must not be null java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'modalComponent' of com/intellij/ide/IdeEventQueue.consumeUnrelatedEvent must not be null at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.$$$reportNull$$$0(IdeEventQueue.java) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.consumeUnrelatedEvent(IdeEventQueue.java) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupportKt$processEventQueueConsumingUnrelatedInputEvents$1.invokeSuspend(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:319) at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284) at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85) at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59) at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source) at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38) at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.PlatformTaskSupport.runBlockingModalInternal(PlatformTaskSupport.kt:76) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.TasksKt.runBlockingModal(tasks.kt:155) at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtilKt.runBlockingUnderModalProgress(ProjectUtil.kt:724) at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtilKt.runBlockingUnderModalProgress$default(ProjectUtil.kt:721) at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction$actionPerformed$1.invoke(OpenFileAction.kt:80) at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction$actionPerformed$1.invoke(OpenFileAction.kt:72) at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.actionPerformed$lambda$0(OpenFileAction.kt:72) at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.ex.FileChooserDialogImpl.choose(FileChooserDialogImpl.java:137) at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:102) at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:80) at com.intellij.ide.actions.OpenFileAction.actionPerformed(OpenFileAction.kt:72) at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:323) at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:302) at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:346) at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:302) at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.performAnActionForComponent(WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.java:101) at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenActionsUtil$ToolbarTextButtonWrapper$1.actionPerformed(WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.java:56) at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972) at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313) at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405) at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262) at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620) at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385) at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995) at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827) at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948) at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575) at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516) at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310) at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780) at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:831) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:753) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437) at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:772) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436) at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434) at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:813) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)`

Please help me to properly open the projects?

**UPD:** the third attempt's full log is here https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nikhil-j-oshi/e902cda1c84a77a121e79c9f21c16256/raw/07d2bc53bf5c0e6a996b6fbad493cfa721e8abbc/gistfile1.txt

Comment: The same error was reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-311312

Can you please try a fresh new installation without importing the previous IDE configurations?

Comment: @EthanYin it doesn't help. I have deleted all configs and caches (Linux) then reinstalled IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2  Build #IC-223.8617.56 . Crashes with different error https://ibb.co/khsR1cx

Comment: @EthanYin ... very strange. The second attempt of opening pom.xml as a project, generates an original error https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nikhil-j-oshi/e902cda1c84a77a121e79c9f21c16256/raw/07d2bc53bf5c0e6a996b6fbad493cfa721e8abbc/gistfile1.txt